# Am I using the right HTML5 tags for my general site layout?

Tags: html

I'm trying to understand the HTML5 elements. I have basic html layout below which I want to migrate to html5 layout. Please have a look at it, and let me know if i'm using it correctly. I'm not sure if I'm using `<section>` and `<article>` correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "wrapper" >

<div id = "left" >
    <div class = "left-box"> ...    </div>
    <div class = "left-box"> ...    </div>
</div>

<div id = "center" >
    <div class = "center-box"> ...  </div>
    <div class = "center-box"> ...  </div>
</div>

<div id = "right">
    <div class = "right-box"> ...   </div>
    <div class = "right-box"> ...   </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**HTML5:**

```
<aside id="left">
    <article class="left-box"> ... </article>
    <article class="left-box"> ... </article>
</aside>

<section id="center">           
    <article class="center-box"> ... </article>  
    <article class="center-box"> ... </article>
</section>

<aside id="right">
    <article class="right-box"> ... </article>
    <article class="right-box"> ... </article>
</aside>
```

PS. As I'm using a div `<wrapper>` to wrap everything, how i use that in html5? Thanks

Comment: “As I'm using a `<div id="wrapper">` to wrap everything, how i use that in html5?” — same as in HTML 4. You use `<div>`s for when HTML5 doesn’t have a specific element for what you’re trying to represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML5:**

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <aside id="left">
        <article class="left-box"> ... </article>
        <article class="left-box"> ... </article>
    </aside>

    <section id="center">           
        <article class="center-box"> ... </article>  
        <article class="center-box"> ... </article>
    </section>

    <aside id="right">
        <article class="right-box"> ... </article>
        <article class="right-box"> ... </article>
    </aside>
</section>
```

This is okay. Remember that html5 elements are just semantic, this means they have to tell their meaning. You have a section with in that section something aside on the left and on the right with between a section with f.e. id content. It's really not that much of a difference.

Instead of setting a wrapper you can also apply these styles directly to "body", but I would not recommend this for the time being (older browsers might give some problems). Also keep in mind that older browsers will probably not recognize these section-tags.

Article is used for... well... articles. So I don't know what you are trying to add in these center-box'es, but use section if they are not articles. It's all in the name... f.e. when you have address data you use the address-tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say whether it's semantically correct or not as we have no idea what the content of the `aside`, `section` and `article` elements are. These (and other) elements are to be used semantically, so the content is key.